# Including a percent calculation in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to write a query that calculates the distinct counts along with percentages according to the diagram below

So far I have part of the query that provides the distinct count of id per color, however how can I include the percentage along with each row in my results?  I first need to total the distinct counts but I was unable to apply the Sum() operation to the result (to sum up all the 'IdCount')

```
        var q = from data in this._data
                 group data by data.Field<string>("color") into groups
                 let name = groups.Key
                 let idGroups= from d in groups select d.Field<string>("id")
                 select new
                 {
                     Color = name,
                     IdCount = idGroups.Distinct().Count()

                 };
```

where

```
this._data
```

is

```
private IEnumerable<DataRow> _data;
```

[image]

Comment: Does simply adding another field to the selection where idGroups.Distinct().Count() is divided by _data.Count() do the trick?

Comment: @Defenestrator I don't think so, the total sum is a sum on the distinct counts of id per group, not the sum of all the id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple approach is to compute total in memory after receiving all the data:

```
var q = ...        // your query here
        .ToList(); // Bring results to memory
decimal total = q.Sum(r => r.IdCount);
var res = q.Select(r => new {
    r.Color
,   r.IdCount
,   Percentage = 100 * r.IdCount / total;
});
```

Using `ToList()` avoids querying the data again on the second pass through the values. Since the number of colors is limited, this query does not put too much strain on system's memory.

Comment: I agree with @dasblinkenlight about making calculation operations on the memory. Grab a well designed query for fetching data faster, then calculate what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Here is working linqpad version:

```
    var _data = new List<Data>{
        new Data {
        id =1,
        color="a",
        },

        new Data {
        id =1,
        color="a",
        },

        new Data {
        id =2,
        color="b",
        }
    };
    var q = from data in _data
            group data by data.color into groups
            let name = groups.Key
            let idGroups = from d in groups select d.id
            select new
            {
                Color = name,
                IdCount = idGroups.Count(),
                Percent = Math.Round((decimal)idGroups.Count() / _data.Count, 2)
            };

    Console.WriteLine(q);
```

Comment: I think this is wrong, the count should be on the distinct counts, not on all the id in a group., In my diagram your count for blue yields 6, but the count I'm looking for is the number of distinct items so that is actually 3

Answer (score 0):

You will have to multiply each group count with 100 and divide by the number of elements, which is Count, so

```
double scalar = 100.0 / this._data;
```

And then use this scalar in your LINQ query:

```
    var q = from data in this._data
             group data by data.Field<string>("color") into groups
             let name = groups.Key
             let idGroups= from d in groups select d.Field<string>("id")
             select new
             {
                 Color = name,
                 IdCount = idGroups.Count(),
                 Percentage = idGroups.Count() * scalar
             };
```

Comment: hot this way, I'm counting the distinct ids per group and totaling those counts